# Call a function inside of an if-statement in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below. I have a function which updates the value of C and D to -99.

```
def func(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if ("C" in col) or ("D" in col):
            df.loc[:,col] = -99
```

Now i just want to call that function, if A =2. I tried the below code but it updates all the rows of C and D to -99

```
import pandas as pd
data=[[0,1,0,0, 0],
      [1,2,0,0,0],
      [2,0,0,0,0],
      [2,4,0,0,0],
      [1,8,0,0,0],
      [3,2, 0,0,0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C', 'D','E'])
df
def func(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        if ("C" in col) or ("D" in col):
            df.loc[:,col] = -99

if (df['A'] == 2).any():
    func(df)
    print(df)
```

My expected output:

```
   A  B   C   D  E
0  0  1  0   0  0
1  1  2  0   0  0
2  2  0 -99 -99  0
3  2  4 -99 -99  0
4  1  8  0   0  0
5  3  2  0   0  0
```

Comment: This snippet `df.loc[df.A == 2, ['C', 'D']] = -99` will give the 'expected output'. It isn't clear to me, what exactly you are trying to do, since the `any()` call would set `-99` to every row of the `C` and `D` columns.

Comment: I just want to call the function only if A == 2